# Is it possible to steal what a person does not believe he owns?

Tags: metaethics, deontology, intersubjectivity

**Expanded question:**

A *theft* is here defined as a *wrongful taking*. To *steal* is to do a theft.

Suppose a hypothetical theft of X does not impede the ability of the hypothetical owner of X to exercise what he believes are his rights to the use of X. (*He* is used as the neuter pronoun throughout.) Is it possible or meaningful to steal X if the putative owner of X, in full knowledge of X and its relation to himself, does not believe he is the owner, and his perception of his rights to the use of X are not infringed?

This question is not about laws pertaining to lawful and unlawful taking or legal assignment of ownership.

---

**Examples for clarity:**

Person A believes he is taking person B's property without his consent. Person B believes person A is legitimately, if perhaps onerously, sharing what neither of them own.

1: Alfred believes that women and girls are their father's property until they are married, whereupon they become the husband's property. Alfred marries a woman without the consent of her father, Baldric. Baldric does not believe that daughters are their father's property. Alfred will not keep Baldric from exercising what Baldric believes are a father's rights in relation to his adult children. Has Alfred stolen Baldric's daughter?

2: Alfred and Baldric are medieval authors. Baldric, a typical medieval, has no conception of intellectual property. Alfred has (improbably) come to believe in intellectual property in the modern sense. Baldric writes a book in Latin. Alfred translates, interpolates, alters, embellishes, and publishes Baldric's book in Middle English without Baldric's consent. Alfred makes no claim against Baldric's ability to use, modify, or distribute either book. Has Alfred stolen Baldric's intellectual property?

---

**My attempt to self-answer:**

My intuition is that the answer is yes in all cases, and that this ought to be a simple question with a straightforward answer.

However, when I try to construct that straightforward answer, I'm getting muddled.

Consequentialism - At least as regards immediate short-term consequences for Alfred and Baldric, it seems that a consequentialist should tell Alfred to go right ahead, since Alfred, Alfred's wife, and Alfred's audience all win, and Baldric doesn't lose. However, short-term consequentialism is notoriously unreliable, and long-term consequentialism is practically impossible to calculate...

Intersubjectivity - our population sample doesn't have an ubiquitous assessment of the underlying facts.

Moral realism - hard to attach to anything unless one can point to some divine or natural law which makes Alfred or Baldric not just morally but *factually* correct.

Deontology - Relying on Alfred's personal sense that he is doing something that is not permitted allows us to conclude that Alfred is doing *something* wrong from a deontological perspective, but it's not clear to me that the *taking* is the wrong thing that Alfred is doing, and not some purely internal sin antecedent to but separate from a permissible taking.

---

**Is it possible to steal what a person does not believe he owns?**

Comment: In German penal law, the objective fact that it is someone else's possession together with the subjective intent to take possession of it is sufficient. The owner's knowledge does play no role.

Comment: And I would think the same is probably true everywhere.

Comment: I have added a line to clarify that this question is not about laws pertaining to lawful and unlawful taking or legal assignment of ownership.

Comment: One cannot steal what another is willing to give away for free.

Answer (score 0):

Person A steals from person B if they take something belonging to person B without permission or some other legal right to do so. Whether something belongs to person B is a legal question- it isn't a matter of person B's belief, so yes, person A can have stolen from person B even if person B believed it wasn't theft. To take a concrete example, let's suppose you buy a new property and you mistakenly believe the boundary lies within the actual legal boundary, so that there is a strip of land you think belongs to your neighbour but is legally yours. If your neighbour does not disabuse you, and instead takes firewood from the strip, your neighbour is stealing your firewood even though you do not believe it to be yours.

Answer (score 0):

Just a recommendation here because I can´t comment on questions yet: I see you wrote a self-answer. Did you know that in StackExchange sites you can answer your own questions? When composing a question you have the option to also submit an answer. Answering one's questions is encouraged per the site´s rules. :)

No onto my answer:

The concept of ownership as it is understood in current Capitalist society has a base in the production for exchange (see Marx's Capital). AIt is only in the context of a society organized this way that the concept of private property has a reality in which to operate. So the concept can only refer to commodities (exchangeable things) and the means of production (means to produce commodities). Everything outside of that is not private property but something else.

So under this understanding, a person can only "own" another person when the slave is seen as a commodity, ie an exchangeable item. That is why your first example does not at all imply ownership. The fact that fathers are protective of their daughters is because of love and jealousy not because they believe they own them like slaves. Because of this, daughters are in fact not property and cannot be stolen. Many confuse jealousy for enforcement of private property.

Your second example fits better on these definitions of ownership. Under current law, ideas have been treated as an exchangeable commodity; copyright and patents are examples of this. But ideas are not physical things and can be reproduced without negating the existence of the previous one (when I share an idea, the fact that the recipients have now that idea in their minds does not mean the idea in my mind is gone). So ownership of this type is very hard to enforce.

Treating ideas as private property is an unrealistic imposition that the subject puts into the idea reather than something that arises from the nature of the idea itself. Because of this it is ontologically impossible to "steal" ideas; they cannot be exchanged like commodities and therefore can't be stolen.

Now, when talking about physical commodities private property makes much more sense because it is a property that arised from the object itself (or rather from how we socially treat the object). Under this understanding, if a person does not believe they own a commodity (ie they do not believe they have the right to exchange a thing) then that thing is an unclaimed commodity that cannot be stolen.

TLDR: No, it is not possible to steal what a person does not believe they own. Be aware not to confuse jealousy with private property since those are totally different problems. Also, private property cannot realistically be enforced on ideas.

Comment: are you still Moral?

Answer (score 0):

A nomad believes no-one owns the land. A settler believes they own the land they settled on. If there is no theft then the law is biased in favour of the settler.

Intellectual property is different. Patent law allows someone the 'ownership' of an idea for a limited time. Originally patents were granted for any entrepreneur who brings in a new and potentially profitable process. If you went to Venice and studied glassblowing, or to the orient and studied how porcelain was made, you could patent these in England. This allowed entrepreneurs a time to recoup their costs for research or travel without being undercut by someone who just copies what they do. The word 'inventor' comes from the Latin invenire - 'to bring in'. This is a short-term expedient to encourage innovation, rather than a fundamental right.